# Eliminar exceso de espacios de una cadena con PHP

Tags: php, html, string

Estoy haciendo una función que al pasarle una cadena de texto por ejemplo:

```
"   Hola    mundo   soy    Alexis     "
```

que me regrese algo limpio sin espacios.

Para espacios al principio y final  hago esto:

```
 function Quitar_Espacios($Frase)
 {
    $frase_sinespacios = trim($Frase)
 }
```

Y me devuelve esto:

```
"Hola  mundo   soy   Alexis"
```

Quita los espacios correctamente del principio y final pero también quisiera que los quitara los espacios en medio de las cadenas dejando solo uno y quedara así:

```
"Hola mundo soy Alexis"
```

Supongo tengo que recorrer el string pero no se si haya alguna función que me ayude. Saludos de antemano.

[image: No se muestran los resultados]

Answer (score 13):

Se puede hacer de forma simple con las funciones `implode()` y `explode()`.

**Actualización:**  Investigando encontré que la función `explode()` podría convertir los espacios en cadenas vacías en lugar de eliminarlos, para que funcione en todos los casos se puede agregar `array_filter()` para eliminar dichas cadenas (el resultado se aprecia mejor en un `<textarea>`):

```
<?php 
function Quitar_Espacios($cadena)
{
  return implode(' ',array_filter(explode(' ',$cadena))); 
}
?>
<textarea cols=30 rows=1><?= Quitar_Espacios('   hola     soy    Alexis   ') ?></textarea>
```

Otra opción es usar `preg_replace()` y las expresiones regulares para eliminar el exceso de espacios en medio de las cadenas y espacios al inicio y al final:

```
<?php 
function Quitar_Espacios($cadena)
{
    return preg_replace(['/\s+/','/^\s|\s$/'],[' ',''], $cadena);
}
?>
<textarea cols=30 rows=1><?= Quitar_Espacios('   hola     soy    Alexis   ') ?></textarea>
```

El resultado debería ser el mismo.

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: No me funciono o no se si la implemente bien :(

Comment: Solo es copiar y pegar, XD yo hice eso y si me funcionó :D

Comment: Ya somos dos, quiero aprender las Exreg pero me confunden XD.

Comment: xD enserio no me funcionó me sigue dejando los espacios al principio al final y en medio :(

Comment: @AlexisMartinez voy a pensar otra opción, tal vez tu versión de php es antigua y no soporta alguna función.

Comment: Es la 5 en esta empresa ._.

Comment: @VickMuñoz por favor evita dejar cumplidos o crear discusiones secundarias, así no creas ruido en las publicaciones. Te invito a leer: [¿Cuándo no debería comentar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @AlexisMartinez prueba la segunda opción.

Comment: Ya quedo +10 linces

Answer (score 4):

Esta función quita todos los espacios duplicados

```
function Quitar_Espacios($Frase)
 {
    return preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", trim($Frase));
 }
```

Comment: Aunque esta publicación puede servir para responder la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace el código compartido. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora este codigo si hace los que estabas preguntando, acabo de modificarlo. claro lo que estabas buscando es eliminar los espacios excendentes y conservar  uno solo entre palabras. (En la salida use PRE por que permite mostras los espacios en blanco)

adjunto codigo:

```
<?php

// funcion para quitar espacios
function Quitar_Espacios($Frase)
{
    $array = explode(' ',$Frase);  // convierte en array separa por espacios;
    $salida ='';
    // quita los campos vacios y pone un solo espacio
    for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
        if(strlen($array[$i])>0) {
            $salida.= ' ' . $array[$i];
        }
    }
  return  trim($salida);
}


$entrada = 'Hola   esta      es una prueba    de separacion   de    espacios';
$salida = Quitar_Espacios($entrada);

 echo '<br> Entrada := <pre>'. $entrada . '</pre>';
 echo '<br>  Salida := <pre>'. $salida . '</pre>';

?>
```

Salida en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! es que no se si me di a entender osea si quiero espacios donde deben de ir pero en caso de la cadena tenga doble espacio o mas entre palabras quitarlos y dejar uno solo. Lo que pones es para quitar todos los espacios completamente.

Answer (score 0):

Ya quedo!

```
   //Quita los espacios innecesarios en una cadena al principio y al final, asi como espacios de mas entre palabras dejandolos en 1 solo.
   function Quitar_Espacios($Frase)
    {
        $Frase_Bien = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $Frase);
        echo "Frase bien: ".$Frase_Bien."\n";
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces/2326133#2326133

Comment: Obtuviste esa respuesta de StackOverflow en Ingles [Remove multiple whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326133/4832311), créditos a su autor.

Comment: Como bien te dice @the-breaker edita y coloca enlace al recurso original **si tienes dudas de como hacerlo, lee este enlace oficial** [referenciar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)